# Finding how many files in an http server using c# and/or java

Tags: c#, java, html

I am not too familiar with HTML. I have a file structure on an HTML based server that is like:

folder A
 ->file 1,2,3,4,5...
folder b
.
.
.
How can I get the list of available files and folders using HTTP requests in c# or java? I can request a URL like: 
http://abc.com/files
Now this page has  tag for the files and folders within this directory. So is there a way to get a list of all the sub files in the folders under this directory???

Hope this makes sense.

UPDATE:
Thanks guys but this is a hard one to explain. Ok so the webpage is generated by a device called AirStash that transmits data contained in a SDcard by creating its own WIFI network and a webpage http://airstash.net/files. The source of the html looks something like this.
....

`<body><div class="centerbox"><div class="logo"><img src="/airstash.png" alt="AirStash&reg;" title="AirStash&reg;"> <span class="SettingsButton"><a href="/settings.html">Settings</a></span></div>
<div id="sorts">
<a class="MedText" href="101DIR00">101DIR00</a>
<a class="MedText" href="102DIR00">102DIR00</a>
<a class="MedText" href="103DIR00">103DIR00</a>
<a class="MedText" href="00001.JPG">00001.JPG</a>`
...
So I am just after a simple way of retrieving these href tags so I can then download the files in that directory for ex in "101DIR00".
I can get this html in a string form and then look for the string after the "href" but that seems like a long tedious method. So just wondering if there is an easier way of retrieving this.

Comment: You could try the `wget` tool to mirror the site at a given point and count the number of files retrieved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are querying via http, then : no, there is no robust way of doing this, and the answer is moot because increasingly the http address doesn't map 1:1 to files *anyway*. Just look at the address above for example (this page, I mean).

You could act like a robot might; look for things like a site-map, else/or spider the pages. But note that aggressive spidering will usually get you blocked pretty quickly.

If you have access to the server's file system, just count the files.